# Using jQuery Validate plugin submitHandler to fire fancybox window

Tags: jquery, iframe, jquery-validate, submit, fancybox

I'm using jQuery Validate & Fancybox together on a website to load a modal Fancybox window on form submission (after being validated by Validate) to confirm an order is being processed but have encountered a weird issue I'm unable to resolve. The < a > tag is as follows on the same page as the form:

```
<a href="<?=ssl_url()?>basket/processing" class="processing" id="submit_holder">PROCESSING</a>
```

In the JS file I have the following config for Fancybox:

```
$(".processing").fancybox({
    'padding'       : 0,
    'width'  : 400,
    'height' : 400,
    'modal'         : true,
    'overlayColor'  : '#fff',
    'overlayOpacity': 0.8,
    'autoScale'     : true,
    'type'  : 'iframe',
    'transitionIn' : 'fade',
    'transitionOut' : 'fade',
    'titlePosition' : 'inside'
});
```

Now, clicking this link directly works fine - loads as expected. When trying to launch via Validate's submitHandler:

```
       submitHandler: function(form) {
            $('#submit_holder').click();
            form.submit();
       }
```

The Fancybox itself loads but completely blank. I can't view any source nor can I open the frame in a new window, it's almost as if the href attribute of the < a> tag isn't being obtained as the iframe src by Fancybox.

Can anyone help? This is driving me completely nuts.

Thanks, Matt

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `$('#submit_holder').trigger('click');` instead of `$('#submit_holder').click();` and also try in other browsers to see if its a browser issue.

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks for your prompt response.

Yes, I have tried .trigger() and across multiple browsers (should have noted this originally) - the weird thing is that the box itself with the config loads it just doesn't load the source (the frame contents).

Comment: In your browser whilst on the page with the form, type into the URL Address the following `javascript: $('#submit_holder').click();` - This will tell me if the .Click() is failing or the `SubmitHander`

Comment: That did launch the box correctly - interesting, any other ideas?

Comment: ok so now you know its not the Click() method. Remove the form.submit(); this will now tell me if the form event is disabling all other actions during submit! and make sure you use `return false;` to prevent the form from executing